# ASP.net and PHP costs, requirements and differences

Tags: php, asp.net

What are the requirements for running asp.net and cost compared to PHP? The ASP.net framework is free and I guess Visual Studio for companies cost money and Windows Server; besides that, are there any other costs?

Is asp.net more suitable for bigger projects? ASP.net is object-oriented but is PHP really object-oriented? As far as security goes what's more secure ASP or PHP?

I'm kind of new to web programming, so try to keep the answers simple.

Comment: Security through obscurity is not security.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. Unfortunately this sort of discursive question has been decided as not a good fit for Stack Overflow. We prefer actual programming questions, so if you want to mull over the pros and cons of a particular language, you might find the chat window better. If you get a moment, read the FAQ.

Comment: FWIW: the .net languages are perfectly capable, but for the most part, if you want to use them you'll need to pay for a Windows license (either directly or via your hosting costs). PHP will run happily on free versions of Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are suitable for bigger projects and both are secure too. But these two things depends on the Programmer or Team you hire. You can have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_languages_used_in_most_popular_websites).

ASP is fully Object oriented and can be written only in OOPS Concept. PHP Can be written in Object oriented as well as Procedural ways. PHP was a Procedural language when it is implemented first but later gained OOPS Principles. Thats why.

PHP is an open source language. It is free to the community and lots of tutorials and examples are available everywhere. ASP.net is free framework but Web server and OS Costs.